# ¿Cómo crear o asignar datos correctamente en la tabla spatial_ref_sys de PostGIS en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, funciones, postgis

Estoy usando *PostGIS* con *PostgreSQL* para usarlo con unos datos de diferentes países de **Latinoamérica**, cargué unos archivos *shape*, primeramente de Colombia.

En **la tabla** tengo 31 departamentos por municipios de Colombia: Amazonas, Antioquia, Arauca, Bogotá, Bolívar, Boyacá, Caldas, Caquetá, Casanare, Cauca, Cesar, Chocó, Córdoba, Cundinamarca, Guainía, Guaviare, Huila, La Guajira, Magdalena, Meta, Nariño, Norte de Santander, Putumayo, Risaralda, San Andrés y 6 más.

Son los departamentos de Colombia, con sus municipios, deseo realizar la función `ST_CONTAINS`. Estas funcionalidades están el *schema* `public` de *PostGIS* y tengo el siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT * FROM colombia.choco where public.st_contains(colombia.choco.geom,
    public.st_transform(
        public.st_geometryfromtext('POINT(6.974971 -77.176609)', 4326),4326
    )
)
```

La geometría *point*, contiene datos de un punto situado en la [región del Chocó](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choc%C3%B3), pero al momento de consultar, no sale ningún dato o me genera el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
> SQL state: XX000

Supongo que en la tabla `Spatial_ref_sys` no encuentra el *SRID*. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que me encuentre el municipio en el que se encuentra el punto `POINT(-75.87793943 5.65916846)`?

Quizás hice algo mal al cargar los archivos *SHP* (los cargué con la función de postgres `Shp2psql`).

Comment: `ST_CONTAINS` no devuelve datos en realidad, devuelve solamente `true` o `false` de acuerdo a lo que dice la documentación: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html

Comment: Qué versión de PostGIS es? En las versiones superiores a la 2 spatial_ref_sys ya no ex relevante. Si existe es sólo por retrocompatibilidad. Segundo, el primer argumento de tu st_contains puede estar en otro srid que el 4326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en mi comentario, PostGIS 2.0+ no hace uso de spatial_ref_sys. Tu problema no tiene que ver con ella.

Tu problema es que estás intentando intersectar o en este caso comprobar la contención entre geometrías cuyo SRID es distinto.

Suele pasar que al subir un shapefile o cargar una gran tabla de geometrías (en este caso los departamentos), el campo de geometría de la tabla quede con SRID = 0. Las coordenadas contenidas en el campo de geometría son válidas acorde a la proyección de Mercator, SRID 4326, pero no lo dicen explícitamente.

La consecuencia de lo anterior es que cuando realizas una operación geométrica te va a decir: No puedo saber si una geometría SRID 0 contiene a una geometría SRID 4326.

Una solución sucia y rápida: fijar el SRID del campo geométrico al vuelo usando [ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)

```
SELECT * FROM colombia.choco 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(6.974971 -77.176609)', 4326))
```

La solución definitiva, por cierto, es actualizar tus tablas de geometrías (los departamentos/municipios de Colombia) aplicando ST_SetSRID a toda la columna.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste a entender la función del Srid dentro de las tablas y muy buena explicación.